# Personal knowledge base and LaTex

Tags: cross-referencing, href

I have two personal knowledge bases (PKB). One is latex which I used to mainly take lecture notes such as linear algebra or algorithms. Another is [logseq](https://logseq.com/) which I used to take notes of research papers, coding ideas and tricks, and daily journal, etc.

I found logseq (or any other double-linked note-taking apps) easier for daily use compared to latex, since it uses a variant of Markdown (meaning that it's easy to edit and move text around, and no compilation!), supports [bidirectional links](https://maggieappleton.com/bidirectionals) (I found it very helpful in gathering thoughts during research), and has katex support (so that I can write a sufficient amount of math formulas). But latex shines when it comes to heavy math contents like my lecture notes. Plus it can be customized easily to create fancy-looking pdfs.

Therefore I think for now I'd rather keep them separate: I don't want to use latex for everything; and I don't want to copy latex into logseq markdown since I love the customizations which are not yet offered by katex. But I need some suggestions to make logseq interact with latex.

Let me be clear, my current workflow is that, I use logseq to take notes. And if I want to refer to some equations in my latex notes (say, Jensen inequality), I will create a new page called `Jensen Inequality` and link to this page. Then whenever I see a link and would like to refresh my memory on Jensen inequality I would take my pre-compiled latex pdf and ctrl-f search for Jensen inequality to see its property and definition etc.

I wonder if there is any better way. Specifically, I'd like to link to a specific equation or section in latex outside of latex. Say if I host my generated pdf on a website (or converted to a html). Then instead of ctrl-f manually each time I want to search for Jensen inequality, I can just click the link and it will direct me to the equation or section location in which Jensen inequality is defined. I can hardcode the section number but I don't want to update it every time when I add/remove new sections in the latex pdf, and by the same token hardcoding a page number also doesn't work.

I don't know if this is even possible. But if linking section and/or equation is possible via a programming interface ie if it's possible to do so by parsing the generated pdf it's also very acceptable. Any pointer or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you use the `hyperref` package, you can refer to labels in your document just using an URL fragment (also know as anchor, the part after a `#` in an URL). For example, if you place `\section[one]{Section One}` into your document and the section title (including the relevant label) happens to be typeset on page number 10, the URL `[path to and name of your document].pdf#one` will open this PDF on page 10.